# Time Series AR model shows NaNs for prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, arima

I'm running the below code for AR model and it returns blanks
Can someone help me debug this.

```
# With Headers
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, cnxn,index_col='date',parse_dates=True)
#index col is required to make sure stasmodel on this dataset we need to set index frequency
df.index.freq = 'MS'


df.to_csv("Billings.csv")
# write back to an excel for audits and testing

#train test split
train_data = df.iloc[:len(df)-12]
test_data = df.iloc[len(df)-12:]

from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR,ARResults

# Ignore harmless warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

model = AR(train_data['tcv'])
AR1fit = model.fit(maxlag=1,method='mle') #max_lag tells you how many co efficients to take or what model type it is. E.g. AR1
print(f'Lag: {AR1fit.k_ar}')
print(f'Coefficients:\n{AR1fit.params}')

# general format for obtaining predictions
start=len(train_data)
end=len(train_data)+len(test_data)-1
predictions1 = AR1fit.predict(start=start, end=end, dynamic=False).rename('AR(1) Predictions')
predictions1
```

Output:
[image: Click here for Image Output]

[Results of print statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khI4D.png)

Comment: Sorry, can you show the result of print statements ... or if you see some warnings. The code looks okay, so I'm wondering if the data has missing entries ....

Comment: Just added the result of print statement for ------>
model = AR(train_data['tcv'])
AR1fit = model.fit(maxlag=1,method='mle') #max_lag tells you how many co efficients to take or what model type it is. E.g. AR1
print(f'Lag: {AR1fit.k_ar}')
print(f'Coefficients:\n{AR1fit.params}')

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for uploading the results of the print statements!

As you can see the value of `L1.tcv` parameter is `NaN`. BTW, To get a better picture of the model fit, you can also do:

```
print(AR1fit.summary())
```

In any case, this explains why you get `NaN`s in your predictions - because any computation with `NaN` will result in `NaN`.

However, fixing this is another kettle of fish. If you look at the vignette [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/autoregressions.html), you can see they use `dropna` in block [3].

I suspect that if you did something similar on your train set, `train_data['tcv'].dropna()`, this could fix your predictions.

Comment: @Kapil Lehar , can you check this is true ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same situation you have faced with this AR Model, and the fix I did was ensuring the df Data Frame you have loaded y the dataset the indexes start with Zero. You could use the next:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```